# times symbol in text mode

Tags: math-mode, text-mode

How can I write the × (multiplication) symbol in text mode?

The journal forbids math in-text like `$\times$`, and nothing is showing up on my searches

Comment: Can you use a package: `\usepackage{ textcomp }` with `\texttimes`

Comment: `\texttimes` should work without the need of any additional packages

Comment: @Lukas indeed! \texttimes works without any additional packages.  If you write your answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In text mode the symbol is `\texttimes`